# How do I make 1/3 cup liquid glucose for toffee apple recipe?

Tags: toffee

I'm about to make Toffee Apples for the kids and have chosen this recipe:
https://www.bestrecipes.com.au/recipes/toffee-apples-recipe/22mx42pc

I don't have or can buy the liquid glucose.
How can I make ⅓ cup?

Comment: see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17106/how-do-i-make-liquid-glucose-from-powdered-glucose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the glucose is to make the caramel more stable. Glucose contains sugars that do not crystallise as easily as regular granulated sugar, so adding it will make it less likely that the caramel will fail. Making glucose at home is not really possible: you need a small chemistry lab to pull it off (you can hydrolyse corn starch with sulphuric acid to get glucose syrup). Instead, you can substitute the glucose with another sugar that also doesn't crystallise easily. Which one is available to you depends on your location, but golden syrup, corn syrup, or light molasses would all serve the same purpose as the glucose.

Comment: If there's a restaurant/bakery supply place nearby, you can buy "invert sugar". But at a regular grocery you're more likely to find something like Lyle's Golden Syrup.